# Using simple math functions when implementing new op in Tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a new op in C++ by writing a .cc file (CPU and GPU versions). This op uses simple math functions like cos or sin.

What is the proper way to call cos or sin (or the likes) on floats in CPU/GPU. Do we have to include an external library ? Is it in Eigen ? Do we have to use different libraries for CPU and GPU ?
How to declare it ?

Is there some more documentations/examples you know of apart from [zero_out.cc](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) ?

Answer (score 0):

I used `std::cos` and `std::sin` and it works fine **ON CPU**! No idea if it is how it should be though, I will keep this answer until someone disproves it.

**EDIT:** Well it seems I have spoken too fast: the GPU version needs CUDA function and not C++ functions (so called host functions).